# Can the Elder Wand be duplicated?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, deathly-hallows

The Elder Wand is apparently a unique, and uniquely powerful, wand.  However, its components are well known: Elder wood, 15" long, and a thestral-hair core.

According to the [HPWiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Elder_Wand), elder wood is very powerful and fickle, and thestral hair is "a tricky substance that only wizards that mastered death can control."  But somebody made the Elder Wand in the first place, and somebody else should, therefore, be able to reproduce the feat.

Theoretically, then, there is no reason why a sufficiently skilled, suitably experienced, and properly motivated wand-maker could not create a new Elder Wand... is there?

And is there evidence that anyone tried it?

Comment: The "somebody" that made the Elder Wand was death himself. And the HP Wiki is not really a good canon source.

Comment: A new wand wouldn't have the knowledge and combined magical puissance of its previous (powerful) owners. It'd just be a wand like any other

Comment: @johnp more likely it was Antioch Peverell, whose feat should be more achievable.

Comment: @valorum but it could acquire that eventually the same way as the original.

Comment: @Hellion - Well, it wouldn't be identical.

Comment: One would think, if it were possible, a sufficiently skilled, suitably experienced and properly motivated wand-maker would have already succeeded in reproducing the Elder Wand. We can't know if this was achieved, but we also don't know for certain that the Death Stick, Wand of Destiny, and Elder Wand are, in fact one-in-the-same. It is merely suggested/surmised that they are.

Comment: @vynsane - Without the combined power of its previous owners, an Elder and Thestral-hair wand would presumably just be any one of a thousand weird combinations that only work for a few people

Comment: @Hellion - Also, the theory that the Peverells were the inventors of the Hallows is just that a theory. Even [JKR's site](https://www.pottermore.com/features/everything-we-know-about-the-elder-wand) doesn't lean one way or the other.

Comment: @Valorum - no one specified that it had to be "identical" - only that it would be a reproduction of the original, using the same 11 secret herbs and spices. Nor, for that matter, was it specified that it had to be recreated with exactly the same amount of power as the original as of the second wizarding war.

Comment: How much of the Elder Wand's power was tied up in its history. Has there been mention of other wands with similar history and age? If so, how powerful were they?

Comment: A wooden club, a Gothic wood carving, and a living tree are all made of the same basic components. However, it takes little skill to create the first, a lot to create the second, and good luck creating the third.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## The Elder Wand was unique, especially due to its long history.

The Elder Wand wasn’t simply a wand made from elder wood and thestral hair - it was a wand that “learned” from many masters since the Middle Ages.

> “Believers in the Elder Wand, however, hold that because of the way in which it has always passed allegiance between owners — the next master overcoming the first, usually by killing him — the Elder Wand has never been destroyed or buried, but has survived to accumulate wisdom, strength, and power far beyond the ordinary.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

This sort of history spanning centuries would be impossible to duplicate in any reasonable time frame, even with a new wand made with the same type and quality materials by a wizard equally as powerful as the Peverell brothers.

However, at least one wandmaker, Gregorovitch, did study the Elder Wand and possibly tried to duplicate it.

> “It was a rumour,’ whispered Ollivander. ‘A rumour, years and years ago, long before you were born! I believe Gregorovitch himself started it. You can see how good it would be for business: that he was studying, and duplicating, the qualities of the Elder Wand!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 (The Wandmaker)*</sup></sub>

Even if he did find out what it was made of, though, he couldn’t make a wand that would be immediately as powerful as the Elder Wand. Theoretically, it might become as powerful as the Elder Wand - but it’d take a while.

### It should be possible to make a wand that’d in time be equally powerful.

The Elder Wand doesn’t have any components that can’t be recreated. Presuming that Dumbledore was right (since he usually is) and the Elder Wand was made by one of the Peverell brothers, not Death, there’s no reason creating a wand that eventually becomes as powerful as it should be at least possible. The talent of the wandmaker might have a part in how powerful the wand can become - the Peverell brothers were said to be extraordinarily talented wizards, so that might have been a factor. However, if a skilled wandmaker makes a wand with the same specifications as the Elder Wand, and it’s passed along for centuries, it should theoretically be as powerful as the Elder Wand. Perhaps the most difficult part would be getting wizards to pass it on into the centuries, since there’d be no legends behind this new wand, and wizards generally tend to prefer their own.

Comment: I'm not convinced. "Elder Wand Mk II" does not imply it has to be a full-on clone of the original, complete with all the accumulated wisdom of its full history. Just that it is a fresh version of the original wand with the potential to be just as powerful given enough time. So, the question is - die Gregorovich succeed in creating a wand with the potential to one day be as powerful as the Elder Wand was at the time of the Second Wizarding War?

Comment: @vynsane Well, my point was it’d take a while before any wand could attain that kind of power - it can’t be created and expected to immediately be that powerful. I’ve edited my answer to address if a wand can ever become as powerful as the Elder Wand given time. It should be - though it’s never said that Gregorovitch did, though he studied the Elder Wand.

Comment: If the replication was successful, and although the new wand is not nearly as powerful as the original, but noticeably more than ordinary wands, then the replication can easily be passed on based on the legend of the original.

Comment: What if someone made the duplicate Elder v2, then mastered the Elder Classic with the Elder v2? Would there be a transfer of power/knowledge?

Answer (score -1):

As with the previous answers, I agree that the wand can be recreated, in time, from it learning from its masters.

Although it was mentioned that the wand was the most powerful one at the time it was created, I'd argue that the wand itself was not that powerful, but the one wielding it having the most superior duel capability in his time. He might as well have just said that false advertisement to be able to duel excellent duelists. The wand then learned from this master and kept the knowledge - supplementing its subsequent owners' skills in due and other aspects which it eventually learned from its masters.

The original wielder has not been bested through a duel but was killed while he was sleeping.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! I'm not entirely sure if this answer actually adds anything but rather just reiterates what is said in other answers (and is unsourced). You also seem to go off on a tangent about the Elder Wand itself without referring back to the main question at hand, could you [edit] to be clearer about this? Remember this is a Q/A site and not a forum.